# im trying to pick a random link to send put i dont know how to get this randomizer to send any ideas? (The Links Are Nsfw)

Tags: javascript

im trying to pick a random link to send put i dont know how to get this randomizer to send any ideas? (The Links Are Nsfw)

```
    client.on('message', msg =>{
      if (msg.content === 'Bruh')
        msg.channel.send("???",{
        file: "http://i.imgur.com/1lJShpM.jpg"}) 
    });

    var randomlinks=new Array()

    randomlinks[0]="http://i.imgur.com/028K3KS.jpg" //all of the links
    randomlinks[1]="http://i.imgur.com/04cay5P.jpg"
    randomlinks[2]="http://i.imgur.com/061DVJL.jpg"
    randomlinks[3]="http://i.imgur.com/061DVJL.jpg"
    randomlinks[4]="http://i.imgur.com/06YTAjg.jpg"
    randomlinks[5]="http://i.imgur.com/07KrOMJ.jpg"
    randomlinks[6]="http://i.imgur.com/088gtko.jpg"
    randomlinks[7]="http://i.imgur.com/1b8OnSq.jpg"
    randomlinks[8]="http://i.imgur.com/1cn1AGk.jpg"
    randomlinks[9]="http://i.imgur.com/1dE9w7D.jpg"
    randomlinks[10]="http://i.imgur.com/1DHyZ1o.jpg"
    randomlinks[11]="http://i.imgur.com/3DdJfok.jpg"
    randomlinks[12]="http://i.imgur.com/3fqMlVa.jpg"
    randomlinks[13]="http://i.imgur.com/34wxctI.jpg"
    randomlinks[14]="http://i.imgur.com/4AUZVaU.jpg"
    randomlinks[15]="http://i.imgur.com/4GeO4fe.jpg"
    randomlinks[16]="http://i.imgur.com/4iLFk9D.jpg"
    randomlinks[17]="http://i.imgur.com/5HfTBtS.jpg"
    randomlinks[18]="http://i.imgur.com/5jtpkEn.jpg"
    randomlinks[19]="http://i.imgur.com/53i5NhS.jpg"


    function randomlink(){
    window.location=randomlinks[Math.floor(Math.random()*randomlinks.length)]
    }

    };
```

i dont know if i can or just scrap it if anyone has a suggestion that would be great